# Variable hides a variable in an enclosing block

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code to expand all PropertyGrid items, I still can't understand what this error means:

> Variable 'g' hides a variable in an enclosing block.

How do I correct this error ?

```
    Dim Root As GridItem = PropertyGrid1.SelectedGridItem
    While Root.Parent IsNot Nothing
        Root = Root.Parent
    End While
    If Root IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim odd As Boolean = False
        For Each g As GridItem In Root.GridItems
            g.Expanded = odd
            odd = Not odd
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: You must be making use of the variable `g` in the surrounding code somewhere

Comment: Post the rest of the method/class. You have another variable called `g` declared somewhere, but you've not posted enough code to show where.

Comment: Thank you, That's true I already found another variable called g declared in the same class.